# Find flow of the vector field $\overrightarrow{\operatorname{rot}F}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, integration

We've given 5 points in $\mathbb{R}^3$: $A=(1,0,0)$, $B=(0,1,0)$, $C=(0,0,1)$, $D=(1,1,0)$, $E= (1,1,1)$. We have a surface $S$ given by triangles $ADE, DBE, BCE, CAE$. We have a vector field: $$\overrightarrow{F}= \begin{bmatrix} xz\\-yz\\\frac{xyz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\end{bmatrix}.$$ My task is to compute flow of the vector field $\overrightarrow{\operatorname{rot}F}$ from negative side (seen from point $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$) to the positive side.
Can somebody show me the solution. My attempt was the following: I found $$\overrightarrow{\operatorname{rot}F} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{xz(x^2 + z^2)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} + y\\x -\frac{yz(y^2 + z^2)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \\0\end{bmatrix}.$$ And my problem is that in every method used to compute the flow of some vector field, we need a parametric representation- here whether parametric representation of $S $ or parametric representation of are bounded by $S$ and triangle $ABC$. I don't know how to find neither of them. Can somebody show me how to solve my exercise?

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* try to compute the flux directly. Use Stokes's Theorem. When you piece the four triangles together, what is the boundary curve?

Comment: Maybe I can compute the flow separately for each triangle? And then sum it together? Well, I can't imagine any parametrization of this curve..

Comment: The curve consists of four line segments. You should be able to compute the work done by $\vec F$ on each of the four quite easily. Yes, you might need to parametrize some line segments. Review that!